# Kubernetes Dashboard open remote acces issue

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-dashboard

I am trying to open dashboard for remote access. I can access from the GUI interface inside the machine.

`>> minikube dashboard`

command works in the machine and I access to the dashboard UI. However, I try to open dashboard for remote access I could not be able to do it. I tried 3 different ways to open.
1 st way https://www.bogotobogo.com/DevOps/Docker/Docker_Kubernetes_Nginx_Ingress_Controller_for_Dashboard_on_Minikube.php. In here

`>> minikube addons enable ingress`

is giving error that i could not be able to find in the forums etc. The error is like
following

- Using image k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/controller:v1.1.1
- Using image k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/kube-webhook-certgen:v1.1.1
- Using image k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/kube-webhook-certgen:v1.1.1

- Verifying ingress addon...

X Exiting due to MK_ADDON_ENABLE: run callbacks: running callbacks: [waiting for app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx pods: timed out waiting for the condition]
*

- If the above advice does not help, please let us know:
  https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/new/choose
- Please run `minikube logs --file=logs.txt` and attach logs.txt to the GitHub issue.
- Please also attach the following file to the GitHub issue:
- - /tmp/minikube_addons_63d5aaebbb272eea44b9208d7275913abf1afd99_0.log

The second way that I've tried -> https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/dashboard/
In here it does not give respond for

`>> minikube dashboard --url`

It is waiting until to keyboard interrupt (CTRL + C)

The last way I've tried -> https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/

In here

`>> kubectl proxy`

does not responding anything. I am cancelling by keyboard interrupt.

Comment: Did you manage to enable ingress?  There is an open [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/13841) on Github and it is not solved yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the second way issue it is my foolish : (  I have to run commands in background : ).